# Gmail on Android corrupt some files

Tags: android, gmail, download

In one of my application, I open binary files, and I got some error report by users on some files. When they send me the files, if I download them on Gmail in the desktop, the file displays nicely in my app. When I download them with the native Android GMail app, the file doesn't open.

Here are the first 64 bytes of the original file, and as it appear when downloaded from the desktop (displayed as hexa):

```
03 00 08 00 D8 0C 00 00 01 00 1C 00 BC 02 00 00 
2D 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 D0 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 10 00 00 00 25 00 00 00 
33 00 00 00 3D 00 00 00 44 00 00 00 49 00 00 00
```

And here are the first 64 bytes of the file downloaded with the native GMail app (hexa again) :

```
EF BF BD EF BF BD 2D EF BF BD 25 33 3D 44 49 4D 
52 63 72 76 EF BF BD EF BF BD EF BF BD EF BF BD 
EF BF BD EF BF BD EF BF BD EF BF BD EF BF BD EF 
BF BD EF BF BD 29 2E 3E 43 54 59 69 6E 7F EF BF
```

Is there a sort of compression applied to this file or is the GMail app corrupting it ? Especially if you look at the end of the first sample, you have the following bytes 10, 25, 33, 3D, 44, 49, which also appear in the first line of the second sample, which leed me to think that it's a compression of some sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure of the exact source, but if you look at http://www.cogsci.ed.ac.uk/~richard/utf-8.cgi?input=%F6&mode=char then that pattern is due to something trying to interpret the file as UTF-8, doing replacement, then writing the file as UTF-8.